# utf-8 encoding and getting a string slice

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a twitter and there's a need to encode the text since in case there is no encoding, there is an exception. But when I use 'utf-8' it doesn't only add b symbol to the console output, but also makes it impossible to access parts of the string. What can I do to fix it or what other encoding should I try?

Here is an example of what happens.

```
>>> a="newyear"
>>> b=a.encode("utf-8")
>>> a
'newyear'
>>> b
b'newyear'
>>> a[0]
'n'
>>> b[0]
110
```

My parser code is the following:

```
tweets=soup.findAll("p", {"class":"TweetTextSize"})  

n=0
for tweet in tweets:  


    n+=1;
    print(n)
    a=tweet.text 
    b=a.encode("utf-8")   
    print(b)   #works fine, but returns bytestring, extra b character,
    #and I can't get b[0]
    print(b.decode("utf-8")) #doesn't work - 
    #UnicodeEncodeError: ‘charmap’ code can’t encode character '\u2026'

    #uncommented try section works, but it replaces "bad" tweets with ops, 
    #which I'd rather avoid
    # try:
        # print(tweet.text)
    # except:
        # print("OPS")
```

So I can handle the exception with try, but I was wondering if there is some other way.

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: b.decode("utf-8")[0]

Comment: @lonewaft, I can't do it - I still have a need for some sort of encoding (the raw text the BeautifulSoup extracts from Twitter gives an encoding error).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ jpmc26, It's Python 3.5.1

Comment: https://twitter.com/aaronsw
The tweet - "The head of the MTA is an anti-government libertarian? Does this mean Joe Lhota is basically Ron Swanson?"

 I guess it has something to do with href link..

Comment: Your first block looks like normal behavior. A `bytes` is not a text string; it's a set of bytes. `110` is just `0b1101110` or `0x6E`. It's the UTF-8 byte for the character `'n'`. Why do you need to convert the string to bytes? If you convert it to UTF-8 bytes, not every character will be a single index anymore; if you're taking slices, you may be splitting up characters and creating byte sequences that are invalid in UTF-8.

Comment: @jpmc26, I see.. But if the encoding's out of question, maybe there's a way to recognize invalid characters and throw them out?

Comment: You could throw out invalid characters by passing [`errors='ignore'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes) to the `decode` method, but *why* are you try to slice the bytes in the first place? This really doesn't make sense. Surely you want to split by *character*, not encoded bytes?

Comment: Like, for instance, in http://www.wired.com/category/science/page/1/ "Crap's Spontaneously combusting.." the `'` character prints out weirdly in console (`\xe2\xe80\x99s`), while on twitter such things would even stop the program if attempted to be printed.

Comment: @jpmc26, That's right. I wasn't really familiar with `utf-8` when I tried that. Used it just as a way to get of an error.

Comment: Printing out `'\xe2\xe80\x99'` sounds pretty normal. It's not an ASCII character, so of course something that can only print ASCII might represent it using an escape sequence. How much do you know about encodings? Are you familiar with the content in [Joel's blog on them](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)?

Answer (score 1):

you are confused about when to `encode` and when to `decode`

if you have a bytestring then you `decode` it into unicode

```
a="a string" 
b = a.decode('utf8') 
#b is now UNICODE
```

if you have unicode you `encode` it to an encoded bytestring

```
a=u"\u00b0C"
b = a.encode('utf8')
#b is now decoded back to a byte string
```

I suspect you are getting a bytestring back from twitter so you probably need

```
b = a.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: I believe I'm getting something else from twitter. Sometimes there are bad tweets with characters which my concole can't recognize (the mistake with those bad posts occurs only if I try to print them out).

Comment: @parsecer : are you on windows? getting unicode to print out on the command prompt is a pain

Comment: your console will try to apply its own encode/decode to interpret the characters ... try printing the `repr`